# "Invalid verification code format." facebook oauth error

Tags: php, facebook

I am a beginner to Facebook app development. I am stuck with an authentication issue, I am trying to use this url:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=http://www.wesbite.com/facebook/&scope=email,offline_access

but I receive this error:
"Invalid verification code format."

I have been trying to solve it for the last three hours and no result. I try to google this message but apparently it is not that popular.

can you please help?

Edit:
I use this function:

```
function get_contents($link)
{
if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
    $curl    = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $buffer;
} elseif (function_exists('file_get_contents')) {
    $buffer = file_get_contents($link);
    return $buffer;
} elseif (function_exists('file')) {
    $buffer = implode('', @file($link));
    return $buffer;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

then I pass the url as a parameter:

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=http://www.mywebsite.com/facebook/&scope=email,offline_access";

`echo get_contents($url);`

Comment: might be useful to echo $url before you call echo get_contents($url), to make sure that all the variables are set.

Comment: I did that and also double checked the values and all of them are correct

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the following link provides the answer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-users-in-a-web-application

You first need to call https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize with your client_id and redirect_uri. This will then redirect you back to the redirect_uri, with a verification code in the query string that you can pass to your https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token call (via the code parameter) to exchange for an oAuth access token.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read that page more than 10 times before your explained the process (I guess I was reading the wrong way). One question though, I am trying to redirect using header(location: xxxx) however instead of redirection I get the facebook button. Clicking on it would take me to the right page though. How do i solve this issue

Comment: Interesting, that sounds like you're using the Facebook JavaScript SDK (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#single-sign-on-with-the-javascript-sdk)? If so, your code should authenticate directly with oAuth 2.0 (i.e. no need for the calls above) providing you have the correct includes (all.js) and scripts (e.g. FB.init) in place. As shown on the linked page above, you can subscribe to the 'auth.login' event and redirect in the callback once the user has authenticated. If you're not using the JavaScript SDK, try removing the <fb:login-button></fb:login-button> tags.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using the PHP SDK. I never used js in any part of the app. If I access the app directly like so: www.mywebsite.com/folder  (this is where I save app's files) I get the right page which is the permissions page.

Comment: Alright. I solved the issue using this code: $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array). then redirecting the page to it. Thank you very much Robarondaz for the solution. Your post is much appreciated.